# Ошибка в передаче пути переменной C++

Tags: c++, графика

```
int gdriver=DETECT,gmode,h,m,s,a,b,c;
initgraph(&gdriver,&gmode,”c:\tc\bgi”);
```

Не хочет следовать указанному пути и выводит ошибку, из-за которой программа падает с ошибкой.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что такое "путь переменной"? Но вообще-то в строковых литералах С++ обратная косая черта записывается как `\\ `.

Answer (score -1):

Очень похоже на borland C. В первой строке исправьте на

```
int gdriver = DETECT;
```

Во второй строке процедура должна быть примерно такой:

```
InitGraph(var Driver, Mode: integer; Path:string);
```

Соответственно gDriver ставите вместо Driver, mode - выберите самостоятельно их не особо много. Путь оставьте прежним.